# Grunt usemin task to replace resources

Tags: gruntjs

Using [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/), is it possible to replace certain resources in an HTML file with a remote path (or perhaps just anypath)? I'm particularly interested in doing this with the [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) plugin.

Possible sample functionality:

#### Before

```
<!-- build:js //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.3/angular.js -->
<script src="/lib/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

#### After

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.3/angular.js"></script>
```

This idea is very similar to what the usemin plugin does but it skips the concatenation of the enclosed resources into a new file of the specified name. In other words, it replaces all the enclosed HTML with a single resource of the specified path.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger) because I found usemin too specific.  You can use grunt-dom-munger to alter your HTML however you see fit and also to read your script tags and send those to concat/uglify/etc.

[grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger)

Answer (score 1):

grunt-applymin is an alternative project for grunt-usemin: https://github.com/ghosert/grunt-applymin

Comment: Just dont provide the link give explaination or paste relevant code